# Picard groups and localization

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Would like some help in solving an exercise in the K-book (Weibel). It has to do with the surjectivity of the base extension map $Pic(R)\rightarrow Pic(S^{-1} R)$ of Picard groups in a specific situation.

Suppose $R$ is a (commutative) Krull domain (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_ring ) and $S$ a multiplicatively closed subset of non-zero elements. Further assume that every height one prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $R$ which intersects $S$ is an invertible ideal. Then the base extension map $Pic(R)\rightarrow Pic(S^{-1} R)$ is onto. This is part (c) of exercise 3.8 in chapter 1 of the K book.

If $R$ is regular, this is immediate via the class group, however, there are mild singularities in the context in which I would like to apply it.

**(EDIT)** *Incomplete solution:* Let $I$ be a divisorial fractional ideal of $R$. This means that it corresponds to a Weil divisor, or more precisely, $I=(R:(R:I))$, see p. 11 of [http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/classgroup.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/classgroup.pdf) for further details. Assume that $I$ is invertible as an ideal of $S^{-1} R$ and thus the equivalence class $[I]\in Pic(S^{-1}R)$. Let $J$ be an inverse of $I$ as an ideal in $S^{-1} R$. Thus the $R$-ideal $IJ$ equals $S^{-1}R$ on inverting $S$. Every height one prime ideal containing $IJ$ must intersect $S$ and thus is invertible. Enumerate these ideals by $\mathfrak{p}_1,\dots, \mathfrak{p}_m$. Let $n_i$ be the order to which a uniformizer in $R_{\mathfrak{p}_i}$ divides $(IJ)R_{\mathfrak{p}_i}$ and $M:=\prod_i \mathfrak{p}_i^{n_i}$.

It would seem that $IJ=M$ on the nose, and, if this is the case, $I(JM^{-1})=R$. As a result, $I$ would be invertible as an $R$-ideal. We would thus conclude that $[I]\in Pic(R)$, and the exercise. However, in order to deduce that  $IJ=M$, I need to show that $IJ$ is divisorial. This is probably the hardest part, and this is where I am stuck.